# getSales java issue

Tags: java, arrays, syntax-error

I must create a sales tracking program named SalesTracking.java. This program will use arrays to store and process monthly sales as well as compute average yearly sales, total sales for the year, and which month had the highest sales and which month had the lowest sales.  I should use parallel arrays. First array (monthArray) should be initialized with all of the months. This array should have 12 locations of course. Other array should be named monthlySales. Like monthArray, this array should be 12 locations that store the amount of sales for each month.

The program should prompt the user for the sales for each month starting with January. The arrays (monthlySales and monthArray) should be created in main and passed to the methods as needed.

I get two errors and the program doesn't run. The errors are on getSales and says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: 
>         Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
>
> ```
>   at getSales.getSales(getSales.java:57)
>   at getSales.main(getSales.java:36)
> ```

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class getSales 
{   
    private static String monthArray[] = 
            {
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                    "September", "October", "November", "December"
            };

    private static double monthlySales[] = new double[12];
    private static int currentMonth = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)      
    {

                double getSales, totalSales, averageSales, highestMonth, lowestMonth, highestSales, lowestSales;            

        for ( currentMonth = 0; currentMonth < monthlySales.length; currentMonth++) monthlySales[currentMonth] = 
                getSales();

        int highestMonthIndex = computeHighestMonth(monthlySales);
        int lowestMonthIndex = computeLowestMonth (monthlySales);

        displaySaleInfo(computeTotalSales(monthlySales), computeAverageSales (monthlySales),
                highestMonthIndex, monthlySales[highestMonthIndex], lowestMonthIndex, monthlySales[lowestMonthIndex]);

    } //End of Main

    private static int getSales()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = monthArray.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthArray[i] + ":");
        monthlySales[i] = input.nextInt();
        //get sales method to store values into monthlysales
    }

    //gets monthly sales and returns total sales for the year
    public static double computeTotalSales(double monthlySales[]) 
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) 
        {
            sum += monthlySales[i];

        }
        return sum;
    }

    //gets monthly sales and returns average sales
    public static double computeAverageSales (double monthlySales[]) 
    {
        return computeTotalSales (monthlySales) / monthlySales.length;
    }

    //determine month with the highest sales
    public static int computeHighestMonth (double monthlySales[]) 
    {
        int index = 0;
        double val = monthlySales[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) 
        {
            if (monthlySales[i] > val) 
            {
                val = monthlySales[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;       
    }

    //determine month with the lowest sales
    public static int computeLowestMonth (double monthlySales[]) 
    {
        int index = 0;
        double val = monthlySales[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < monthlySales.length; i++) 
        {
            if (monthlySales[i] < val) 
            {
                val = monthlySales[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;

    }

    //displays all the sales data rounded to two decimal places
    public static void displaySaleInfo (double totalSales, double averageSales,
            int highestMonth, double highestSales, int lowestMonth, double lowestSales) 
    {

        System.out.printf("TotalSales: %.2f" , totalSales);
        System.out.printf("AverageSales: %.2f" , averageSales);
        System.out.println("HighestMonth: " + monthArray[highestMonth]);
        System.out.printf("HighestSales: %.2f" , highestSales);
        System.out.println("LowestMonth: " + monthArray[lowestMonth]);
        System.out.printf("LowestSales: %.2f" , lowestSales);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you think `insert "}" to complete Block` means? Be more specific about the issue you are having in your question title.

Comment: There was a { missing. Having issue with returning the value on getSales.

Comment: So, have you now fixed the compilation problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your routine getSales the line `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){` does not have a matching close bracket `}`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious missing `}`, your getSales() function and your main() function are trying to do the same thing.

```
public static void main(String[] args)      
{
    // ...
    for ( currentMonth = 0; currentMonth < monthlySales.length; currentMonth++) 
        monthlySales[currentMonth] = getSales();
```

This code suggests that you want getSales() to return a single int for a given month.

```
private static int getSales()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = monthArray.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthArray[i] + ":");
        monthlySales[i] = input.nextInt();
    //get sales method to store values into monthlysales
    }
}
```

This code suggests that you want getSales() to fill the monthlysales array.

You'll either need to adjust getSales() to return a single int, like so:

```
monthlySales[currentMonth] = getSales(monthArray[currentMonth]);

private static int getSales(String monthName)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthName + ":");
    return input.nextInt();
}
```

Or you'll need to have `getSales()` return an array and adjust your main function accordingly.